# Is it good idea to batch multiple merge in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, merge

I am trying to write a stored procedure where I do multiple insert/Update/Delete on different tables.

So my SP looks like this. Is this right way to do?

```
Begin
  Merge 1
End
Begin
  Merge 2
End 
Begin
  Merge 3
End
```

Or I should follow like this

```
Begin
  Merge 1
  Merge 2
  Merge 3
End
```

Help!!

Comment: Your BEGIN/END segments do not really create multiple batches, so there really is no difference between these two options. Did you mean BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT TRANSACTION?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I understand if I use BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT TRAN as a batch, this create separate batch. The reason for asking this question was to see how sql server handle them.

Comment: No, it's still not a separate batch, it's a separate transaction. BEGIN/END are just code blocks and have nothing to do with batches.

Answer (score 3):

You should have it as follows:

```
Begin
  Merge 1
  Merge 2
  Merge 3
End
```

See @AaronBertrand's comments above for further clarification.